# why brew link mtr not work in macOS catalina

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am install mtr in macOS catalina:

```
brew install mtr
```

but when I using this command:

```
/usr/local/sbin ⌚ 22:53:15
$ mtr
zsh: command not found: mtr
```

and I try to link:

```
/usr/local/sbin ⌚ 22:52:50
$ brew link mtr
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.93_1
To relink:
  brew unlink mtr && brew link mtr
```

why the link not work?

Comment: Is `/usr/local/sbin` in your `PATH`?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/q/925240/185127

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NOTE: For Apple Silicon machines the PATH is different.

Add this line(s) to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

```
# Intel
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin

# Apple Silicon
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/sbin
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc` or close/open your terminal.

Then run mtr as usual

```
sudo mtr 1.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the linked dir not in my macOS path,using this command to check:

```
env | grep sbin
```

try to do this to make it work:

```
# add this line to .bashrc
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

# make it work
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

As to October 8th 2022, none of the previous solutions worked for me (Macbook Pro 15 2019, MacOs Catalina). Here is what I did, following instructions [in here](https://support.rise.ph/article/404-mtr-macos).

> Once mtr is installed, run the command:
>
> `cd /usr/local/Cellar/mtr/0.92/sbin`
>
> Make the mtr command available to your system by running:
>
> `sudo cp mtr /usr/local/bin`
>
> `sudo cp mtr-packet /usr/local/bin/`

I hope it helps.